# How to make a LTXexample-like environment by using the package listings.sty only?

Tags: listings

For some reason, I am forced to create a LTXexample-like environment.

The following is my effort, but it cannot work. :-)

I don't know how to fix the problem.

Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[dvips,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
    literate=   {ï}{}0
                {»}{}0
                {¿}{}0,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\sffamily\bfseries,    
    commentstyle=\color{OliveGreen}\itshape,                                    
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    backgroundcolor=\color{Yellow!30},
    language={PSTricks}%
}

\usepackage{pstricks}


\newcommand{\temporary}{}

\newenvironment{myLTXexample}%
{%
    \renewcommand{\temporary}%
    \bgroup\ignorespaces%
}
{%
    \egroup%
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}%
            \begin{lstlisting}
                    \temporary%
            \end{lstlisting} 
    \end{minipage}
    %
    \hspace{5mm} 
    %
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
            \temporary
    \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myLTXexample}
testing.... \LaTeX !
\end{myLTXexample}

\end{document}
```

EDIT 1: This example is the simplified version of my real scenario. :-)

Comment: `\renewcommand{\temporary}%`?

Comment: @Kilgore, ?????

Comment: why can't you use LTXexample? Your example defines nothing new?

Comment: @Herbert, I need more flexible way to put code region and formatted region. For example, I want the code part in the left cell and the formatted part in the right cell of a tabular row. There are many formations I want to make that is difficult to obtain using LTXexample.

Comment: then look at the package environ, it can collect environments and lets you use it later.

Comment: The (unfinished) `ydoc` bundle does something like that. Check its source code. See the `examplecode` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working solution with fancyvrb. The & before `\tabularnewline` is needed, the code itself is read by the hedaer definition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks,fancyvrb,array,listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small}

\def\endExample{\end{VerbatimOut}
  \input{\jobname.tmp}}
\newcommand\Example{%
\VerbatimEnvironment
\begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} m{0.5\linewidth}@{} 
                    >{\lstinputlisting{\jobname.tmp}}m{0.5\linewidth} @{}}

\begin{Example}
\pspicture(3,2)
\psframe*[linecolor=blue!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{Example}
& 
\tabularnewline

\begin{Example}
\pspicture(3,2)
\psframe*[linecolor=red!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{Example}
& 
\tabularnewline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. It is very satisfactory result.  19 hours must be elapsed to send the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

You can't collect your listing in a command "for later use". listings has to change a lot of catcodes and this won't work when the code has already been read (catcodes are fixed at this moment). You would need `\scantokens` to reset them.

Also you can't hide `\end{lstlisting}` deep in some code: listings has to find the end of the listing without executing the code in between. That's why listings has its own `\newenvironment` command (`\lstnewenvironment`).

If you want to write your own LTXexample you will have to copy the method of showexpl. Basically LTXexample does this:

```
\newenvironment{LTXexample}
{\lst@BeginWriteFile{\SX@codefile}} %At start of env begin to write the code to a file
{\lst@EndWriteFile % stop writing to file
  %now reinput code file \SX@codefile "as listing"
  %reinput code file "as result"
}
```